# Quit model fitting after no improvement

Tags: r, logistic-regression, model-fitting, glmulti

I am using glmulti to fit a logistic regression model. I have 6 predictor variables, with one predictor variable having 84 levels. Consequently, it is taking an exceptionally long time to fit the model. I thought I structured the code to stop running after no improvement in the best model using the conseq argument, but even after 2,000 models with no improvement, it just keeps going. How can I get the model fitting to stop after no improvement? This is the code I am currently using:

```
detectmodelsexbirdpw<- glmulti::glmulti
(outcome ~ sex + bird + year + month + obsname + season, 
data=detect, 
level=2, 
fitfunction=glm, 
crit="aicc", 
family=binomial, 
confsetsize=10, 
conseq = 10, 
deltaM = 0.05, 
deltaB = 0.05, 
plotty = F)
```

I also tried setting the method to "g", but that code gets stuck on initialization and doesn't produce anything, even after letting it run through the night.

Comment: ?? If you have six *input* variables (even if one has 84 levels), and consider models on the level of input variables (not the expanded set of predictor variables, i.e. columns of the model matrix), which IMO is the sensible thing to do, there are a total of 2^6 = 64 models; it should be perfectly feasible to do all-subsets model selection (e.g. see `MuMIn::dredge()`) ... am I missing something?

Comment: Wouldn't 2^6 only be applicable to a model with main effects? I would like to include pairwise interactions in my model. I have run the code with main effects only, and that isn't a problem. Doesn't take long at all. The issue arises when I run the code with pairwise interactions. It runs, but it takes hours. The best model doesn't improve after the first 1000 or or so models, so I would like the code to stop running after "x" amount of models with no improvement, but I haven't been able to make that happen.

Comment: OK, I take it back - there are 15 (`choose(6,2)`) pairwise interactions, and so a lower bound of 2^15 = 32768 models .  I can still definitely think of ways I would rather approach this problem (regularization etc.), but the problem makes sense. (Have you tried the leaps-and-bounds `method ="l"` option ... ?)

Comment: I haven't tried that...I would prefer to stick with the glmulti package.

Comment: `method = "l"` (leaps and bounds) is one of the methods available in `glmulti` ...

Comment: I gotcha...Didn't realize that! I thought the methods argument was limited to "h", "d", and "g". I will look into it.